# how to crop an image get from ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How to crop an image get from ajax?

```
function showDeletePopup(id)
{
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax.php",

}).done(function (data) {
    $('#simplediv').html(data);
});

}
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(function(){
    $('.1').Jcrop({
    aspectRatio: 1,
    onSelect: updateCoords
    });

});
});
function updateCoords(c)
{
    $('#x').val(c.x);
    $('#y').val(c.y);
    $('#w').val(c.w);
    $('#h').val(c.h);
};

function checkCoords()
{
    if (parseInt($('#w').val())) return true;
    alert('Please select a crop region then press submit.');
    return false;
};
</script>
<form action="index.php" method="post" onSubmit="return checkCoords();">
      <input type="hidden" id="x" name="x" />
      <input type="hidden" id="y" name="y" />
      <input type="hidden" id="w" name="w" />
      <input type="hidden" id="h" name="h" />
      <input type="submit" value="Crop Image" class="btn btn-large btn-inverse" />
    </form>
<div id="simplediv" ></div>
```

I use this code crop image got from ajax but the image cannot be cropped....?
I cannot select the image using `imageareaselect()`.
Without using ajax image show, the crop code will work on it..

Comment: What does ajax.php return? What type of content? Is it a link? Include the source of ajax.php.

Comment: Surely you should be using `get` instead of `post` for your ajax call?

Comment: just an image name only, we cannot apply image area select in that image....